# Page generated by CreatePage for Gatsby Throwing Error

Tags: reactjs, tags, jsx, gatsby

I'm adding tags to my Gatsby blog and generating a page that will query all posts with that tag. The page was generating, but the posts weren't showing up. I reworked the code, and now this error is showing up:

```
Original error fixed. see update below.
```

Here is my template file:

```
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import * as React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout"
// import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const TagList = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  const title = pageContext  
  const { totalCount } = data.allMdx.group

    
 
    return (
        <Layout>
          <h3>{ data.allMdx.group.fieldValue }</h3>
          <ul>
            { data.allMdx.group.map( ({ nodes }) => {
              return (
                <li key={ nodes.id }>
                  <Link to={ `/blog/${ nodes.slug}` }>{nodes.title}</Link>
                </li>
              )
            }
            )}
          </ul>
          <Link to="/blog">All tags</Link>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default TagList;

export const query = graphql`
query MyQuery($tags: String) {
  allMdx(
    filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: [$tags] } } }
    ) {
    group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
      fieldValue
      nodes {
        id
        slug
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

and here is my gatsby-node.js file:

```
const path = require(`path`)
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    const tagTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/tagTemplate.js');

    const result = await graphql(`
    query Tags {
      allMdx {
        group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
          fieldValue
          nodes {
            id
            slug
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `)
    if (result.errors) {
      console.log(result.errors);
      reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error whil running GraphQL query`);
    }


    const tags = result.data.allMdx.group
    tags.forEach(tags => {
      createPage({
        path: `/tags/${tags.fieldValue}/`,
        component: tagTemplate,
        context: {
          tags: tags.fieldValue
        }
      })
    });

};
```

Yes, I read the Gatsby documentation several times. It hasn't solved my problem. Neither has Google.

UPDATE:

I managed to get it working part way. The pages show up, but there's no data coming up. It's undefined, and I'm not sure why.

I updated the code blocks above to reflect the changes I made. I'm not getting an error, otherwise I'd post that.

Comment: Can you provide a Codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

So, the error was in my query. Even though it brought up results in the GraphQL tool, it wasn't doing it on the actual page. When I stipulated that the results couldn't be null, the page didn't generate. The way I was querying the data had to change. Here is the new query:

```
query($tags: String!) {
  allMdx(
    limit: 2000
    sort: {fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC}
    filter: {frontmatter: {tags: {eq: $tags }}}
  ) {
    totalCount
    edges {
      node {
        slug
        frontmatter {
          title
          tags
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also called info through the props, just to make sure I was getting everything. Here is how that looks:

```
TagList.propTypes = {
  pageContext: PropTypes.shape({
    tag: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMdx: PropTypes.shape({
      totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      edges: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          node: PropTypes.shape({
            frontmatter: PropTypes.shape({
              title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
            fields: PropTypes.shape({
              slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
          }),
        }).isRequired
      ),
    }),
  }),
}
```

It wasn't throwing an error during generation because there was no error. At that time, a null query wasn't an error. I changed my gatsby-node. Here is what it looks like:

```
const path = require(`path`)
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    const tagTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/tagTemplate.js');

    const result = await graphql(`
    query Tags {
      allMdx {
        group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
          fieldValue
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
    
    `)

    if (result.errors) {
      console.log(result.errors);
      reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error whil running GraphQL query`);
    }


    const tags = result.data.allMdx.group
    tags.forEach(tags => {
      createPage({
        path: `/tags/${tags.fieldValue}/`,
        component: tagTemplate,
        context: {
          tags: tags.fieldValue
        }
      })
    });

};
```